# Is it possible to get loaded image original dimensions and byte size in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

If I have an image item in QML, is it possible for me to find out the original dimensions of the image and its byte size?

For example, if I have the following QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Image {
    source: "http://someURL.jpg"
    asynchronous: true
    sourceSize.width: 800
    sourceSize.height: 600
}
```

Can I get the image's original dimensions and it's byte size after it is completely loaded? I wasn't able to find such properties in the documentation of `Image`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I have an image item in QML, is it possible for me to find out the
>   original dimensions of the image and its byte size?

The problem with async load is that we need to know the moment when the image is ready and there is a way to do so. QtQuick Image has property [status](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#status-prop) to which we can attach the signal:

```
Image {
    source: "http://someURL.jpg"
    asynchronous: true
    onStatusChanged: {
      if (status == Image.Ready) {
         console.log('Loaded: sourceSize ==', sourceSize);
      }
    }
}
```

So we should rather read from `sourceSize` but when ready.